# Maxscript Material/Slate editor?

Tags: editor, shader, maxscript

Hey guys is there a way to access "Material Editor: Manual Update Toggle" for both Slate editor and compact in maxscript?? was looking through the docs but cant seem to find much. any help is appreciated, thanks!!

Comment: Anyone?? is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't updating materials happen automatically? or do you maybe mean "update preview"?

I know that when you do a loop for all your materials, you can via code update the loop and all of its functions by deciding when to trigger the function.

You can acces those materials + all of its functions with something like:

(libile can be external file of internal from your editor)

```
local tempLib = loadTempMaterialLibrary libFile
for m in tempLib do (
                        global materialName = #(m) 
                    )

local materialcount = templib.count
for iterations = 1 to materialcount do 
                    (
-- whatever you like to do
)
```